# ERROR 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

Soy nuevo en esto de la programacion, pero me interesa mucho el tema y me puse a aprender algunas cosas en sitios web y asi de a poco eh llegado a tener una pagina web, pero me eh quedado estancado en un problema que tengo y es que estoy intentando ingresar comentarios a mi base de datos y aun no eh podido

me sale ese error mi código

```
<?php
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['publicar'])) {

                                            $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
                                            $texto = $_POST['comentar'];
                                            $autor = $_SESSION['nombre_usuario'];
                                            $publicaciones = rand(1, 100);

                                            $comentario = new Comentario('', $autor, $publicaciones, $titulo, $texto, '');
                                            RepositorioComentario::insertar_comentario(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $comentario);
                                        }
                                        ?>
```

y en mi RepositorioComentario tengo la funcion

```
public static function insertar_comentario($conexion, $comentario) {
    $comentario_insertado = false;

    if (isset($conexion)) {
        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios(autor_id, entrada_id, titulo, texto, fecha) VALUES(:autor_id, :entrada_id, :titulo, :texto, NOW())";

            $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);

            $sentencia -> bindParam(':autor_id', $comentario -> obtener_autor_id(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentencia -> bindParam(':entrada_id', $comentario -> obtener_entrada_id(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentencia -> bindParam(':titulo', $comentario -> obtener_titulo(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentencia -> bindParam(':texto', $comentario -> obtener_texto(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $comentario_insertado = $sentencia -> execute();
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print 'ERROR' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return $comentario_insertado;
}
```

Agradeceria mucho una ayuda

---

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta David
La estructura de mi base de datos es la siguiente...

```
 CREATE DATABASE blog
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

    USE blog;

    CREATE TABLE usuarios (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nombre VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        fecha_registro DATETIME NOT NULL,
        activo TINYINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE entradas (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
        activa TINYINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(autor_id)
            REFERENCES usuarios(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE comentarios (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        entrada_id INT NOT NULL,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(autor_id)
            REFERENCES usuarios(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
        FOREIGN KEY(entrada_id)
            REFERENCES entradas(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE recuperacion_clave (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        usuario_id INT NOT NULL,
        url_secreta VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id)
            REFERENCES usuarios(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que te aparece te está informando de que estás intentando insertar un registro que requiere que haya sido introducido previamente otro en otra tabla, para que entonces puedas referenciarlo. Es decir, la definición de restricción por clave ajena.

Por tu `INSERT`, tiene toda la pinta de ser `autor_id`:

```
INSERT INTO comentarios(
  autor_id, entrada_id, titulo, texto, fecha
) VALUES(:autor_id, :entrada_id, :titulo, :texto, NOW())
```

Prueba a insertar el autor y, después, el comentario. Pues, si no hay autor, no deberías poder registrar un comentario.

Para poder ayudarte, mejor que el código en PHP, necesitaríamos la estructura de la base de datos. Preferiblemente en SQL (phpMyAdmin,Exportar).